# How to use StreamReader.ReadAsync(Memory<Char>, CancellationToken)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to use [StreamReader.ReadAsync(Memory, CancellationToken) overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readasync?view=netcore-2.1) that accepts a `Memory<T>`.
Here's the sample code: (.NET Core 2.1)

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string code = "Hello, World";
    var memoryStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code.ToCharArray(), 0, code.Length);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(memoryStream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        // var text = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        // Console.WriteLine(text); -> Outputs: Hello, World

        Memory<char> memory = new Memory<char>();
        await reader.ReadAsync(memory);

        Console.WriteLine("Memory<char> length:" + memory.Length);
    }

}
```

Code tries to read string content through `StreamReader` and populate `Memory<char>`. However, code keeps outputting 0 for `Memory<char>` length.

What's the proper way to use this method to populate `Memory<char>` ?

My `.csproj` file content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: are you writing or reading from memory  await reader.ReadAsync(memory);?

Comment: Trying to read from stream to memory.

Comment: As a test, remove everything which is `async`, does your code work without it?

Comment: @CodingYoshi nope, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The working solution is to initialize memory with a buffer and to care the return value of ReadAsync so you know how many characters (not bytes) you did read.

You did run into the issue that Memory is a struct which always allows you to create an instance with no arguments although from an API usage perspective this is not allowed.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadMemory
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string code = "Hello, World";
            var memoryStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code.ToCharArray(), 0, code.Length);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(memoryStream))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {

                Memory<char> memory = new Memory<char>(new char[1024]);  // Init with backing buffer. Otherwise you are trying to read 0 bytes into a zero sized buffer. 
                int charsRead = await reader.ReadAsync(memory);

                Console.WriteLine($"Memory<char> len: {memory.Length}, bytes read: {charsRead}");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

To answer you second question. Yes you can use the ReadAsync(char[] ...) instead of memory. They are equivalent since under the hood it is passed further as System.Memory anyway which is then when it comes to the actual reading converted to a Span anyway. 
See

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> ReadAsync(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
{
    return this.ReadAsyncInternal(new Memory<char>(buffer, index, count), default(System.Threading.CancellationToken)).AsTask();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.If I need to pass backing buffer I would probably use `reader.BaseStream.Length` instead of `1024` to initialize it. Second, don't you think introducing buffer (char array) means I can use [the other overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readasync?view=netcore-2.1#System_IO_StreamReader_ReadAsync_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_) which accepts char array, and then wrap Memory<T> around it  myself ?

Comment: @Michael: Yes you can. See my updated answer. Why did you want to use Memory<T> in the first place?

Comment: I'm using `Memory<T>` to mimic scenario, where I receive content through network for example. So I'm handed `NetworkStream` and need to process data. I'm really having problem seeing the benefit of `Memory<T>` overload if the only way to use this API is to pass buffer, why this overload exists at all ? If I need to create buffer anyways, I would create it, pass to method that writes content to buffer, and wrap it in `Memory<T>` and use that.

Comment: Memory<T> is simply a wrapper around a part of an array with a start index and and length. That way you can share one big array and write with different Memory<T> instances to to corresponding parts. They needed to add Memory<T> because Span can only life on a thread stack and can never be a class member.